# Why doesn't DSolve work here?

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to run this code (where f1, f2 and a1 are positive constants):

```
$Assumptions = {f1 > 0, f2 > 0, a1 > 0, r > 0};
DSolve[-4 f1 r A[r] - 2 (a1 - f2) A[r]^(3/2) - 
   f1 r^2 Derivative[1][A][r] + 
   Sqrt[A[r]] (-2 f2 + 
      4 (-a1 + f2) r Derivative[1][A][r] + (-a1 + f2) r^2 (
        A^\[Prime]\[Prime])[r]) == 0, A[r], r]
```

The boundary conditions are that $A[r],A'[r],A''[r]\to 0$ as $r\to$ infinity but I can't put that in directly.

Comment: I thought your two fractional powers of A[r] might be one issue. Tried replacing A[r] with a[r]^2 and modify all the derivatives accordingly. Unfortunately, if I didn't make a mistake, that didn't help.

Comment: This second-order nonlinear ODE may very well not have a symbolic solution in terms of known functions.  Remember that `DSolve` applies known methods to solve differential equations.  It does not develop previously unknown methods.